# Can Statistical Models and Machine Learning Models be used to make Predictions about Individuals?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, inference, model

In the context of using statistical models to make individual predictions, I have often heard of the "Ecological Fallacy":

[image]

This is a particularly relevant problem in statistics. If you have a dataset and you are interested in creating a statistical or a machine learning model that will make predictions about unseen data at the "individual level" - to what extent does the ecological fallacy complicate this goal?

This seems to be logical on one level : if you collect data on a limited number of individuals, any statistical model  will implicitly assume that all other individuals from the population will be similar to the data you have collected - and whenever this is not the case, the statistical model will be unable to make reliable predictions.

On the other hand, statistical and machine learning models are quite often used for predictions at the individual level. For example, Convolutional Neural Networks have been used to classify individual X-rays for diseases:

[image]

Thus, these are my conclusions:

- Perhaps the Ecological Fallacy can be avoided if enough data is available, such that patterns in unseen data is likely to be represented within the available data (e.g. millions of x-rays)?
- In a more classical setting (e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/202485), big data was not available which made the Ecological Fallacy more of an issue - but  with enough data, the Ecological Fallacy can be mitigated.
- However, when you have many variables - the "Curse of Dimensionality" means that you will begin to require more and more rows of data for the "space" to be "less sparse". This could mean that in datasets with many variables, the Ecological Fallacy along with the Curse of Dimensionality can further complicate statistical modelling.

[image]

Are my conclusions correct? Can a large number of observations potentially reduce the "Ecological Fallacy"?

Comment: You have a lot of unrelated comments mixed up in your question. Ecological fallacy is about models built on aggregated data then applied to disaggregated data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I have incorrectly used the "ecological fallacy" term in this problem. In general, I am interested in knowing if statistical models and machine learning models are in fact intended for predictions at the individual level. thank you!

Comment: Yes, they are intended to be used on whatever you call individual level. Just look at how they translate your texts into different languages, label your photos, chat with you on websites etc

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think what you are describing is only possible with machine learning models in modern times when we have access to large amounts of data (e.g. pictures, text). But when you consider statistical models in environments when there are smaller datasets (e.g. migration patterns for whales), and you only have data on 2 types of whales, and 100 observations for each type of whale: it might be more difficult to generalize the results of a statistical model to unseen whales? thank you!

Comment: Statistical models do not work well when training data comes from a different distribution than the data to forecast. This applies to both “old” and  “new” models.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible that the narwhals and orcas you observe have a different pattern than beluga whales, but if you never observe any beluga whales, why do you feel that you have any business making predictions about them? (I can think of reasons why, but I’d like to hear your rationale.)

Comment: @ Dave: thank you for your reply! "why do you feel that you have any business making predictions about them?" . You have none - but the problem is that in real life you might not know if you are observing a whale, a narwhal or a beluga.

Comment: Then why would you feel like you have any business making a prediction about that animal?

Comment: This was just an example. Suppose you are studying diabetes patients, and create a model for these patients. But in your new data, you have some patients with diabetes but also have undiagnosed conditions (e.g. severe asthma) that neither you nor them know. Thus, your model might end up unknowingly being used on patients that are different from the data used to create the model.